# Render is not a function e-commerce React component

Tags: reactjs, render

I use the class component in my Cart.js file but it got the error as "render is not a function". I also try changing it into a function component but it's not working either, please help me to find a way to fix it! Thank you so much!

My sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-buz0u?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cart` component has error, because you're using `Consumer` from `ProductContext` in a incorrect way. Change it this code will solve the problem:

```
import React from "react";
const ProductContext = React.createContext();

export default class Cart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Consumer>
          {(value) => {
            return <div>hello</div>
          }}
        </ProductContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does it demand a value?

Comment: @naha See the documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer

Comment: Excuse me, i got error again as i tried to set the value to the cart destructuring. Can you help me if you don't mind. Link:https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-buz0u?file=/src/cart/Cart.js

Comment: @naha You don't need to define `const {cart} = value`. You just need to use `{value}`!

Comment: @naha Did my answer help?

Comment: Well, not really cause it still has problems...:https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-buz0u?file=/src/cart/Cart.js

Comment: @naha see this link : https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-forked-khrwk

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, i've run into the same problem again as in my CartList component value is not defined so i can't display my cart item. It'd be kind of you if you can help me! Thank you so much! Sandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-buz0u?file=/src/cart/CartList.js

Answer (score 0):

Please change your cart component

```
import React from "react";
const ProductContext = React.createContext();

export default class Cart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductContext.Provider value={null}>
          hello
        </ProductContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: THank you so much! However, i got error again as i tried to set the value to the cart destructuring. Can you help me if you don't mind? Link:https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-buz0u?file=/src/cart/Cart.js

Comment: please pass value argument like <ProductContext.Provider value={null}>

Comment: What do you mean?